# spans change place with CSS

Tags: css, positioning

I know, that HTML is HTML and CSS is CSS, so please no answers like: You should do that in another way. I want two spans to change place. I don't want to hack this Wordpress plugin, so I want to do it with js (I know how to do that) or even better, with CSS.

This is the code:

```
<span class="count">(0)</span><span class="label">Recommend</span>
```

They look like this now:

```
(0) Recommend
```

And I want them to look that way:

```
Recommend (0)
```

Is that possible with pure CSS? I could imagine something with absolute positioning.

Comment: float the `.count` span `right` and the other one `left`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes do this

Used to this css

```
.count{float:right;}
.label{float:left;}
```

do not make the position:absolute;

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can change the position of the both of the span like below
Recommend(0)

```
                    **OR**
```

Keep your own code without changing the position of span in your code just put the following css in your respective css file. [Demolink](http://jsfiddle.net/U9hKg/1/)
Recommend (0)

```
.count {
   display:inline-block;
}
.label {
    float:left;
}
```